# javascript/json .length returning 1 for array of length 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following javascript:

```
var emails_array = ["[\"theiremail1\",\"theiremail2\",\"theiremail3\"]"];
var emails_array_length = emails_array.length;
alert("emails array: " + emails_array + "emails array length: " + emails_array_length);
```

The alert that appears as the result of this code is:

```
emails array: ["theiremail1","theiremail2","theiremail3"]emails array length: 1
```

Why isn't it returning 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an array with only one item:

```
var emails_array = [
    "[\"theiremail1\",\"theiremail2\",\"theiremail3\"]"
];
```

What you're likely after:

```
var emails_array = JSON.parse(["[\"theiremail1\",\"theiremail2\",\"theiremail3\"]"]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wtLo7h7s/

Answer (score 0):

I think because of the escape characters and your initial double quotes `""`. I have tested this a couple times and everytime I use your syntax of `var emails_array = ["[\"theiremail1\",\"theiremail2\",\"theiremail3\"]"];` the length comes out 1 because of the initial quotes.

Perhaps a simpler string would work?

For certain, `var emails_array = ['theiremail1', 'theiremail2', 'theiremail3'];` will provide an `emails_array.length` of 3...

This gives me a `.length` of `3` in my test environment anyway. If you MUST use your original double bracketing  because you actually want a string with brackets in it then the following works for me.

`emails_array = ['[theiremail1', 'theiremail2', 'theiremail3]'];` which will have a `[` in position 0 and `]` in position 2 if thats what you want.

The way you currently have your array setup it is actually only 1 length long because your first double quotes `""` tell the compiler to see everything as one big string and it cannot see your delimiter `,` character.